# Bootstrap 3.0 Carousel - not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

So I want to implement the above carousel into my page and seem to have multiple problems with it. The page in question is: http://wasup.si/test-bid1

As you see it looks like it doesn't even start...no console errors whatsoever. Can anyone help me out here what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!-- Carousel
                ================================================== -->
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <?php
                            $query = "select * from bcuPhoto where ID_bcu='".$BID."' and published=1";
                            dbOpen2($query);
                            $i=1;
                            while (dbGetRow2()) {
                                $image = Image::getInstance();
                                $pic_big = $image->img(row2('source'),"media/uploads/bcuPhoto/",1170,600,false);
                                unset($image);
                    ?>
                    <div class="item<?php if ($i== 1) print " active"?>">
                      <img src="<?php print $pic_big?>" class="img-responsive" border="0" title="<?php print row2('title')." - ".$i?>">
                    </div>
                    <?php
                                $i++;
                            }
                            dbClose2();
                    ?>
                  </div>
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

This is the code used for the carousel...

Comment: could you post the relevant code here or create a jsfiddle.http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
#myCarousel
{
    height:300px; //set the height
    width:100%;   //set width accordingly
}
```

That'll make it work. Otherwise, there is no problem in your code.

Comment: That did it...the width was indeed 0px...that's why I wasn't seeing it. Now I need to find out how to make images stick to one another (dynamic width)